# android app tab layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have recently started making android apps.

I want to make a app with a few tabs and each tabs has a different title and when u go on it the tab has information and pictures that you can scroll through.

How do i do this ive gone the the main xml in my res/layouts/main.xml and had a look round and found a tab thing but when i drag it on and run a emulator it just come up with the welcome thing i typed as a little hello world kinda thing what do i do please help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tutorial on Android.com
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: yer ive also looked at this thing called droiddraw

Comment: ive looked at that but it dosent really tell you how to put things on the tabs like pictures text and the abillity to scroll down

Comment: one more thing i cant seem to find my project folders in my workspace theres nothing there where are they